# SQL Problem: Using CONTAINS() doesn't work, but LIKE works fine

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search

I have a Products table in a SQL Server database and I am having to troubleshoot a legacy stored procedure that uses Full-Text indexing. For our purposes here, lets suppose that the Products table has two fields ID, Keywords. And the Keywords field is populated with the following:

> ROLAND SA-300 This Roland SA-300 is
>   in MINT condition!

When I run the following statement, I am able to retrieve the record:

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Keywords LIKE '%SA-300%'
```

However, when I run any of the following statements I get zero results:

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE CONTAINS(Keywords, ' SA-300 ')
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE CONTAINS(Keywords, 'SA-300')
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE CONTAINS(Keywords, '"SA-300"')
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE CONTAINS(Keywords, '"*SA-300*"')
```

But I know that the CONTAINS() function is working because I get results when I run any of these:

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE CONTAINS(Keywords, ' Roland ')
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE CONTAINS(Keywords, 'Roland')
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE CONTAINS(Keywords, '"Roland"')
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE CONTAINS(Keywords, '"*Roland*"')
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE CONTAINS(Keywords, 'Roland')
```

I need to figure out why the CONTAINS() function isn't working  on the 'SA-300' term. I am new to Full-text indexes, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: No clue, but have you checked that the index is current?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Two thoughts:

(1) The hyphen might be treated as a word break
What do these return?

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE CONTAINS(Keywords, 'SA')
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE CONTAINS(Keywords, 'SA 300')
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE CONTAINS(Keywords, 'SA300')
```

See this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042/why-doesnt-sql-full-text-indexing-return-results-for-words-containing/1061).

(2) Have you tried rebuilding your full-text index? It is possible it is out of date.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out that I needed to re-build my full-text index. Thanks for the tips @MichaelGG and @JohnFx

Answer (score 2):

Ah! Thank you @GregD. We had a search that wasn't finding the string "this never ends" when looking for "this*" or "never*". Turns out **both** words are in noiseENG.txt.

It doesn't look like it's possible to turn this off on a per-query basis, but based on this:
[SQL 2008: Turn off Stop Words for Full Text Search Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435602/sql-2008-turn-off-stop-words-for-full-text-search-query)

I ran

```
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON MyTable SET STOPLIST = OFF
```

and we started getting the results we wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at your noise words file?  On my machine it's located here c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\FTData\noiseENG.txt

One way that you could test this is by editing your particular noise file with just a single space so that it indexes everything and try your query again.  I would "test" this in a test environment and not in production.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE CONTAINS(Keywords, ' "SA-300" ')
```

I saw an example of what you are trying to do on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa172870(SQL.80).aspx).

Comment: I didn't know if the white space mattered. I guess not.