# SQL: Like vs Contains - Different Results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I'm running two queries on a table.

```
SELECT MSDS FROM dbo.MSDSSearch3 WHERE CONTAINS(MSDS, 'STYCAST')
```

And

```
SELECT MSDS FROM dbo.MSDSSearch3 WHERE MSDS like '%STYCAST%'
```

The first query will return

```
'STYCAST 50300 LV'
```

And the second will return

```
'STYCAST 50300 LV'
'STYCAST 2851 BLACK'
```

Does anyone know why the like would return more values than the contains? Is there a problem with how I'm running contains? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? If 2008 you can get some visibility into the parser with `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_fts_parser('"STYCAST 2851 BLACK"', 1033, 0,0)` I can't see any reason why the strings would be treated differently though.

Comment: Interesting question, are you sure that both values are exactly the same? as in no leading / trailing whitespace characters. That could cause this issue as the CONTAINS would match exactly your text whereas the LIKE would match your text + anything either side of it

Comment: Sounds like a case where your fulltext catalog is out of date. You might want to try rebuilding it with an [ALTER FULLTEXT CATALOG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176095.aspx).

Comment: I thought of that, and ran a like 'STYCAST%', with the same result. The server is running Microsoft SQL Server 2008. I'll keep messing around with it, and let you know if I see anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: @CoreyB - In 2008 you can also query `sys.dm_fts_index_keywords` to see what is indexed.

Comment: Thanks Joe, after I got ahold of a system administrator rebuilding the fulltext catalog worked. The query is running smoothly now!

Comment: @Corey: Glad that worked out for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Problem: Using CONTAINS() doesn't work, but LIKE works fine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588025/sql-problem-using-contains-doesnt-work-but-like-works-fine)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a similar post, where rebuilding the fulltext catalog seemed to solve the problem:

[SQL Problem: Using CONTAINS() doesn't work, but LIKE works fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588025/sql-problem-using-contains-doesnt-work-but-like-works-fine)

Answer (score 2):

CONTAINS is a totally different function, it is a predicate based query for full-text columns; it is not a function to determine if a column contain a string in it.

For the query you are running, you could use this:

```
SELECT MSDS FROM dbo.MSDSSearch3 WHERE CONTAINS(MSDS, '"STYCAST*"')
```

There you have a prefix search, instead of a simple_term search like you currently have.

More details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx

---

Maybe in the way you are using it the text 'STYCAST 2851 BLACK' don't fall into results because it have one more character than 'STYCAST 50300 LV', so it is a [7 of 17 match] vs a [7 of 16 match]. I'm not sure but that could explain this strange behavior.

Comment: Just tested this solution, with the same result.

    SELECT MSDS FROM dbo.MSDSSearch3 WHERE CONTAINS(MSDS, '"STYCAST*"')

Still returned the one value.

Comment: Sad to read that; Then it should be an outdated catalog, but you said you already updated it. It is very strange.

Comment: What if you run this: SELECT MSDS FROM dbo.MSDSSearch3 WHERE CONTAINS(MSDS, 'STYCAST 2851 BLACK') ?

Comment: Sorry, no I haven't updated yet, I should have been more specific. Currently in the process of getting a hold of the server administrator. Hopefully that will solve the issue.

Comment: As for the second question, if I run the query with the full contains, I get the error: Msg 7630, Level 15, State 3, Line 1
Syntax error near '2851' in the full-text search condition 'STYCAST 2851 BLACK'.