# Why the fulltext search does not find word "большой"? (russian)

Tags: sql, full-text-search

I have many results for:

```
select * from Sent_NORMAL_TOKENS with(nolock) where normal_tokens like 'большой%'
```

But I haven't anything for

```
select * from Sent_NORMAL_TOKENS with(nolock) where CONTAINS (normal_tokens, '"большой"')
```

And I have not a stop-list:

```
select * from sys.fulltext_stopwords - is empty list
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688891/sql-like-vs-contains-different-results this answer suggests fulltext catalog could be out of date and suggests this MS article to correct it https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176095.aspx

Comment: I have not a solution :(( 
I look this all indexed words: SELECT * FROM sys.dm_fts_index_keywords( DB_ID('trazo'), OBJECT_ID('Sent_NORMAL_TOKENS') ) 

But there is no my word Большой in this list ? Why? What i must do?

Comment: I think you need to rebuild/update the full text index like my links suggest.  I would search for how to do that if there isn't enough information in the second link.  Sorry I don't have definitive code for you I don't deal with fulltext search much.

Comment: After ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON Sent_NORMAL_TOKENS SET STOPLIST = OFF there are all results. But why select * from sys.fulltext_stopwords and select * from sys.fulltext_stoplists are empty? Where is the stop list? My sql - 2014 version

Comment: I found this: There is select * from sys.fulltext_stopwords, but else there is select * from sys.fulltext_system_stopwords

Comment: I suspect it has nothing to do with you turning off the stoplist and more to do with  ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON forcing the index to rebuild which then captured the word.  Try turning back on stoplist and see if your query still works.