# Search with CONTAINS in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have created a student table and has the following records.

[image]

I want to perform search on the same table. I tried with the following query.

```
SELECT * FROM Students WHERE Name LIKE '%AM%'
```

It returns First two rows as resultset, which is correct.

I would like to perform the same query using the keyword CONTAINS, instead of LIKE.

I tried the below query, but its not returning any resultset.

```
SELECT * FROM Students WHERE CONTAINS(Name,'"AM"')
SELECT * FROM Students WHERE CONTAINS(Name,'"AM*"')
SELECT * FROM Students WHERE CONTAINS(Name,'"*AM*"')
```

Kindly help me to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the column in a [full text index](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317.aspx)? Apart from that it's `'AM'` instead of `'"AM"'`.

Comment: Read the documentation for `contains` (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx).  The second paragraph gives a bulleted list of what `contains` can search for.  Patterns in the middle of a word is not in the list.

Comment: Hi Tim,

Appreciate your reply.
Can you please tell me, How can I create a full text index on this table?

Thanks

Comment: [how to create fulltext index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189520.aspx)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588025/sql-problem-using-contains-doesnt-work-but-like-works-fine

Comment: @Sanoop which one is a primary key here??

Comment: @NagarajS : ID is primary key

Thanks

Comment: I have tried following code to create fulltext index.
But still it doesn't work with CONTAINS.

    'GO
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ui_ukJobCand2 ON Student(Name);
    CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG ft2 AS DEFAULT;
    CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON Student(Name) 
    KEY INDEX ui_ukJobCand2 
    WITH STOPLIST = SYSTEM;
    GO'

Comment: @Sanoop It showing any error??

Comment: @NagarajS : Fulltext index created successfully. But the query is not returning any result.

Comment: try `ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON tablename SET STOPLIST = OFF`

Comment: @NagarajS : ALTER Query executed successfully. But still CONTAINS not returning any resultset.

Comment: @Sanoop have you got result??

Comment: @NagarajS : This works for beginning string. If I use middle characters, its not returning the result.

Comment: @Sanoop oh.this is function behavior or something else?

Comment: As per my understanding CONTAINS doesn't work for middle characters.

Answer (score 0):

Define Full-Text Index for your table column and execute your query.

sample to add Full-Text Index : 
[Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on table or indexed view because it is not full-text indexed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003240/cannot-use-a-contains-or-freetext-predicate-on-table-or-indexed-view-because-it)

Comment: How can I search for middle characters?

Answer (score 0):

1. Start MSSQLFDLauncher (SQL Server -> Config Tools -> Config Manager -> Full-text Filter Daemon Launcher -> Start)
2. Run this code (or something like this with your necessary index)

   CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_ID ON Students(ID)

   CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG Students_Catalog
3. You can't use full-text search with the middle of the word, using CTE is not correct too (because of full-text index), so we'll try to use some tricks...
4. Add function that split names and make each letter like a word

   /*
    Author:        Paul Simpson (modified by Alex Peshik for test purposes!)
    Create date:   7/19/2012 (modified 5/6/2014)
    Description:   Puts spaces+underscores between letters. Example: "GEORGE" becomes "_G _E _O _R _G _E" */

CREATE FUNCTION udf_PutSpacesBetweenChars

```
(@String VARCHAR(100))

RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @pos INT, @result VARCHAR(100); 
   SET @result = @String; 
   SET @pos = 2 -- location where we want first space 
   WHILE @pos < LEN(@result)+1 
   BEGIN 
       SET @result = STUFF(@result, @pos, 0, SPACE(1));
       SET @result = STUFF(@result, @pos+1, 0, '_') -- add underscore (to imitate word)
       SET @pos = @pos+3; -- (the original was +2)
   END 
   RETURN '_'+@result; -- add leading underscore (the original is w/o it)
END
```

1. Add new column and index on it (we can't use persisted computed column as far as it's non-deterministic column).

   ALTER TABLE Students ADD NameSpaced varchar(100)

   UPDATE Students SET NameSpaced=dbo.udf_PutSpacesBetweenChars(Name)

   CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON Students (NameSpaced) KEY INDEX IX_ID ON Students_Catalog;
2. Use special technique to search near letters/'words'. Distance between words is 1, TRUE means only that order ("a,m" and not "m,a").

   SELECT * from Students WHERE CONTAINS(NameSpaced,' NEAR((_a,_m),1,TRUE) ')

Sorry that solution is quite huge, I have no ideas how to simplify it...