# Contains search on the word "after" fails

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Basically running the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM document 
WHERE contains(cachedText, 'after')
```

returns 0 records, same with any search term with the word `after` in it.

Searching for:

```
SELECT * 
FROM document 
WHERE cachedText like '%after%'
```

returns about 200k records in my dataset. Just wondering if there is any reason for this?

Comment: it might have to do with the fact that the second parameter in CONTAINS is nvarchar?

Comment: also take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588025/sql-problem-using-contains-doesnt-work-but-like-works-fine

Comment: `CONTAINS` is the full-text searching in SQL Server, which also defines a list of **stop words** that are not being considered when searching - and there's a fair chance that "after" is considered one of those stopwords and therefore won't be found. Also check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435602/sql-2008-turn-off-stop-words-for-full-text-search-query

Comment: The two queries are completely different. The first is a full-text search query, the second is a simple pattern match. The first probably won't even run if `cachedText` isn't part of an FTS index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query matches the word "after", i.e. a *distinct word* within other text. (If "after" is in the stopwords list then it is ignored entirely.) You can read about the details at [Full-Text Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017#like).

The second query matches "afternoon", "crafters", "dafter", ..., i.e. any string containing "after" regardless of word breaks.

Examine the matches that the second query returns and you'll likely find "after" embedded in longer words.

Comment: The stoplist was the issue, turning it off for the table worked